# pictures belong to which drawable folder

Tags: android, drawable

you kown android has many folder to place picture file.And now, I want to kown my picture belong to which folder(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi...)? thank you

Comment: can you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: if my phone is mdpi, but I don't kown which folder put picture. then how can I kown the folder puts the picture that I used。

Comment: For that, you can put different pictures in all 3 folders with the same name and when you run the app, you will see that on this particular device, which folder's image was used. But I still don't understand why you want to do this?

Comment: here pictures should be totally different but their name should be same in every folder.

Comment: If one picture put in mdpi folder, and I don't kown the folder has the picture.And my phone maybe is hdpi.Then how can I get the folder which folder puts the picture.I only want to kown the pictue I used is belong to which folder.

Comment: Thats why I am saying that put pictures in all 3 folders i.e. in hdpi, put Lion's pic; in mdpi, put dog's pic and in ldpi, put bird's pic. But this pic's name should be same in all the folders i.e. name should be mypic.png in all 3 folders. Now when your app is running , the pic named mypic.png will be shown to you. If its a Lion's pic , then your phone is using hdpi folder; if its Dog's pic then your phone is using mdpi folder and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports several configuration qualifiers that allow you to control how the system selects your alternative resources based on the characteristics of the current device screen.

If you are a beginner and you dont have these different qualities of that single resource. place it anywhere, and link to that. Android SDK will automatically adjust and place it for urself.

For more information see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: If one picture put in mdpi folder, and I don't kown the folder has the picture.And my phone maybe is hdpi.Then how can I get the folder which folder puts the picture.

Comment: SDK will by itself place the picture in all the folders, where you haven't placed it specifically... You don't have to worry about these issues.

Comment: No， I don't worry the place which picture should place. I want to find the folder which the picture used,then I need record the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Read here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: if my phone is mdpi, but I don't kown which folder put picture. then how can I kown the folder puts the picture that I used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that all depends on what types of pictures you're going to use.

For example, app logos are to be stored in the following way (for best use):

```
Size     |     Directory   
36x36    |     drawable-ldpi/
48x48    |     drawable-mdpi/
72x72    |     drawable-hdpi/
96x96    |     drawable-xhdpi/
```

Regular images to be included in the app could be scaled down using a 8/6/4/3 scale, leading to the following:

```
Directory        |     Scale % 
drawable-xhdpi/  |     100%
drawable-hdpi/   |     80% (of xhdpi)
drawable-mdpi/   |     50% (of xhdpi)
drawable-lhdpi/  |     37.5% (of xhdpi)
```

Comment: if my phone is mdpi, but I don't kown which folder put picture. then how can I kown the folder puts the picture that I used.